# Есть ли разница между этими двумя решениями?

Tags: javascript, if

**Задача**

Напишите код, который будет спрашивать логин с помощью *prompt*. Если посетитель вводит «Админ», то *prompt* запрашивает пароль, если ничего не введено или нажата клавиша *Esc* – показать «Отменено», в противном случае отобразить - «Я вас не знаю».

Пароль проверять так:

- если введён пароль «Я главный», то выводить «Здравствуйте!»;
- иначе – «Неверный пароль»;
- при отмене – «Отменено».

[image: Блок-схема]

---

Решение автора:

```js
let userName = prompt("Кто там?", '');

if (userName == 'Админ') {
  let pass = prompt('Пароль?', '');
  if (pass == 'Я главный') {
    alert('Здравствуйте!');
  } else if (pass == '' || pass == null) {
    alert('Отменено');
  } else {
    alert('Неверный пароль');
  }
} else if (userName == '' || userName == null) {
  alert('Отменено');
} else {
  alert("Я вас не знаю");
}
```

Моё решение:

```js
let whoareyou = prompt("ti kto?", '');

if (whoareyou !== "Admin" && whoareyou != null) {
  alert("ya vas ne znau");
} else if (whoareyou == null) {
  alert("otmeneno");
} else(whoareyou == "Admin")
let pass = prompt("PASS:", '')
if (pass !== "main" && whoareyou != null) {
  alert("neverniy parol")
} else if (pass == null) {
  alert("otmeneno")
} else if (pass == "main") {
  alert("ZDRAVSTVUITE!")
}
```

Имеет ли место быть вариант моего решения или это ...код и вообще всё неправильно?

Comment: Ваше решение не рабочие, т.к. есть ошибка синтаксиса. Блок else не требует проверки условия

Comment: @Дмытрык скорее всего он просто пропустил "if". А 2 решение слишком многословное

Comment: Когда так много условий, через if это не читаемо, лучше делать через switch.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, такая реализация вполне читаема.

Надеюсь эта задача для общего развития и Вы не собираетесь использовать это в продакшене!)

```js
var username = prompt("Кто вы?", '');

if(username !== null) {
    if(username == "ADMIN") {
        var pass = prompt("Введите пароль:", '')

        if(pass === null) alert("Отмена")
        else if(pass == "main") {
            alert("Вы авторизовались!")
        }
        else alert("Ваш пароль неверный")
    }
    else alert("Я вас не знаю");
}
else alert("Отмена");
```